# PDF picker -- like a media picker -- is it possible?

Tags: pdf, ios, ios4, ibooks

I've used MPMediaPickerController to select media items (audio recordings) from the user's iPod library. I'd like to do something similar to select PDF files from the user's iBooks app. Is there anything similar to MPMediaPickerController for PDFs in iBooks?

I looked through the list of SDK frameworks and did some Google searches and didn't find anything, but I'm still hoping it exists...

Answer (score 1):

I should have asked my question more broadly, because I really just want to give the user the ability to load PDF files onto the device and then select them from within my app. They don't have to go through iBooks, I just thought that would be the easiest way to get PDFs onto the app.

Anyway, I just discovered the UIFileSharingEnabled option, which lets users copy documents directly to my application via iTunes. Once the files are copied onto the device, my app can find them using [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (the documentation has some good code samples). So that's what I'm doing now and it works great.

Comment: Hi @arlomedia thanks for answer, can you please review your answer for current dated. I googled & also went through many Q&A in stack but confusing. So what is the good way to browse pdf or doc formatted files from our app & then upload to our server. Thanks

Comment: If you want to browse files that are stored in your app's data directory, you can use NSFileManager, linked above. As of iOS 8, there is a new Document Picker you can use to browse files stored in iCloud or in other apps, if the other app supports it. I think that is the only way to browse files stored outside of your own app.

Comment: Document Picker programming guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/

Comment: Thanks @arlomedia that's the answer i was looking for. Did apple working on any common storage of Files as if gallery like images , video etc ?

Comment: There's no document library that works like the photo library and music library, and no way to access PDFs from iBooks like I had originally hoped I could do.